# Where can we ask questions related to the Arabic language of tge Quran?

Tags: arabic

I'm reading the Quran and in many places I can't find the reason behind fatha, kasra and damma.

For example:

وَقَدْ مَكَرُوا مَكْرَهُمْ وَعِندَ اللَّهِ مَكْرُهُمْ وَإِن كَانَ مَكْرُهُمْ لِتَزُولَ مِنْهُ الْجِبَالُ - 14:46

makr**A**hum vs. makr**U**hum and they both mean "their plan". So why with two diffetent vowels?

Where can I ask these types of questions related to Arabic language of the Quran?

Comment: Something similar to your question has already been asked here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/what-is-the-difference-between-kafiroon-and-kafireen/

Comment: For understanding the reason you must learn Arabic grammar and conjugation. For an Arabic speaker the reason is clear. Further in the qur'an the perspectives change a lot. So without an Arabic background it is hard to follow. We may answer your question case by case, but without doing efforts on your site to learn and understand Arabic just reading letters and diacritics won't help.

Comment: So can I ask them here? Would they be on-topic?